# viewWillAppear on a childViewController from the center viewController of a IIViewDeckController not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdeck, iiviewdeckcontroller

Ok here's the problem if you had some trouble understanding the title.
I'm using [this](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) library here and it is represented by the `IIViewDeckController`.

I init it with simple left and center `UIViewControllers` :

```
FTPhoneHomeViewController *home = [[FTPhoneHomeViewController alloc] init];
FTPhoneSideViewController *side = [[FTPhoneSideViewController alloc] init];

IIViewDeckController *vdc = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:home leftViewController:side];
[self.delegate changeRootViewController:vdc];
```

`FTPhoneHomeViewController` and `FTPhoneSideViewController` are just subclasses of `UIViewController`. The last line removes the current `rootViewController` from the window and adds the `IIViewDeckController`.

Now in the `FTPhoneHomeViewController` I add another `UIViewController` with the `addChildViewController` method :

```
FTTileViewController *tileViewController = [[FTTileViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 50.0, 469.0, 310) tileData:[FTTileFaker prepareTileData] defaultTileConfig:[FTTileFaker prepareTileConfigs][0] andTileConfigs:[FTTileFaker prepareTileConfigs]];
tileViewController.tileSpacing = 9.0;
[self addChildViewController:tileViewController];
[self.view addSubview:tileViewController.view];
[tileViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I did this because this `FTTileViewController` manages a bunch of tiles and from an architectural point of view, this logic is best contained in it's own seperate `UIViewController`.

When I use the `IIViewDeckController` as a `rootViewController` from the window, my `viewWillAppear` event in the `FTTileViewController` is not called. But it is called in the `FTPhoneHomeViewController`! Now when I don't use the `IIViewDeckController` and just add the `FTPhoneHomeViewController` as the `rootViewController` of the window, my `FTTileViewController` does get the `viewWillAppear` event...

Maybe it's a bug with the `IIViewDeckController` and I should also post it there. But I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Anyone has any thoughts about this?

And if anyone could check my general assumption around `UIViewControllers` :

Adding `childViewControllers` to another `UIViewController` is not a requirement to get view cycle methods (like `viewWillAppear`) to be passed onto another `UIViewController's` view. These events are passed when you add another `UIViewController's` view with the `addSubview` method. But you use the `addChildViewController` methods for example, to get rotation events and to maintain the `viewController's` hierarchy through your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok to awnser my own question :

In the `IIViewDeckController` there are some methods that you can adjust :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
    return YES;
}
```

return YES from all of them and it should work.
If there is no property for this view containment on the `IIViewDeckController`, maybe it's nice to add it?

Comment: Just got word from the creator, this will be fixed in the next major release!